# Unserialize PHP data in python

Tags: php, python, drupal, deserialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read/make sense of a PHP serialised data string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408599/how-to-read-make-sense-of-a-php-serialised-data-string-in-python)

I'm using python to access a database which is managed by a Drupal install. The data I want to access in Drupal in saved in the database as a PHP serialized object.

Are there any pre-built python modules which can deserialize a PHP serialized object into a python object? I've done some searching and come up with nothing.

I realize I could write my own parser from scratch but I'd rather use something thats been tried and tested.

Comment: You shouldnt save any data in a language-specific format. Use a more common format, like JSON, instead (as long as its possible).

Comment: I have no control over how the data is stored. I only need to access it.

Comment: Seriously?  You think JSON isn't language-specific?  It's in the name.  It's just been widely adopted.

Comment: @PaulC: From the opening paragraph on [`json.org`](https://www.json.org/json-en.html): "JSON is a text format that is completely language independent". You're confusing its origin and name with what it actually *is*.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Are you looking for [phpserialize](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/phpserialize)?

Comment: There's a Python library for everything...

Comment: Indeed there is. Thanks for this. Saved me a LOT of work.

Comment: OMG, Thank you. Python 3rd part libs saved me.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need object serialization (which can be compensated with associative arrays), then a faster alternative might be this: http://code.google.com/p/serek/ (it's a Python module written in C)

It's used in production servers under **heavy** load at my company, so I might recommend it as stable. There is no tarball available, though. So you have to grab it straight from the repository.