# Python unserialize PHP session

Tags: php, python, session, serialization

I have been trying to unserialize PHP session data in Python by using **phpserialize** and a **serek's** modules(got it from [Unserialize PHP data in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935501/unserialize-php-data-in-python)), but it seems like impossible to me.

Both modules expect PHP session data to be like:

```
a:2:{s:3:"Usr";s:5:"AxL11";s:2:"Id";s:1:"2";}
```

But the data stored in the session file is:

```
Id|s:1:"2";Usr|s:5:"AxL11";
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: With **phpserialize** I have tried to do the following:
    
    `>>> loads('a:2:{s:3:"Usr";s:5:"AxL11";s:2:"Id";s:1:"2";}')`
    `{'Usr': 'AxL11', 'Id': '2'}`

This works, as you can see, but with my REAL PHP session data stored in a file:

    `>>> loads('Id|s:1:"2";Usr|s:5:"AxL11";')`

I get a ValueError at phpserialize.py", line 444, in _expect

Comment: In my php.ini file I have the following:

session.serialize_handler = php

More info at [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.serialize-handler)

Comment: After reaching page 3 on Google, I found a [fork](https://github.com/nathanwalsh/phpserialize) of the original [phpserialize](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/phpserialize) that worked with the string that I privided:

    `>>> loads('Id|s:1:"2";Usr|s:5:"AxL11";')`
    `{'Id': '2', 'Usr': 'AxL11'}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default algorithm used for PHP *session* serialization is *not* the one used by [`serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php), but another internal **broken** format called [`php`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.serialize-handler), which

> cannot store numeric index nor string index contains special characters (`|` and `!`) in `$_SESSION.`

---

The correct solution is to **change the crippled default session serialization format** to the one supported by Armin Ronacher's original [`phpserialize`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/phpserialize) library, or even to serialize and deserialize as JSON, by changing the [`session.serialize_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.serialize-handler) INI setting.

I decided to use the former for maximal compatibility on the PHP side by using

```
ini_set('session.serialize_handler', 'php_serialize')
```

which makes the new sessions compatible with standard `phpserialize`.

Answer (score 2):

After reaching page 3 on Google, I found a [fork](https://github.com/nathanwalsh/phpserialize) of the original application [phpserialize](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/phpserialize) that worked with the string that I provided:

```
>>> loads('Id|s:1:"2";Usr|s:5:"AxL11";')
{'Id': '2', 'Usr': 'AxL11'}
```

Comment: The fork doesn't work with Python 3. Armin Ronacher's original code was carefully crafted to be 2/3 polyglot, however this fork breaks it. See my answer for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it in a stupid way:

At first, convert `Id|s:1:"2";Usr|s:5:"AxL11";` to a query string `Id=2&Usr=AxL11&` then use `parse_qs`:

```
import sys
import re

if sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
    from urllib.parse import parse_qs, quote
else:
    from urlparse import parse_qs
    from urllib import quote

def parse_php_session(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as sess:
        return parse_qs(
           re.sub(r'\|s:([0-9]+):"?(.*?)(?=[^;|]+\|s:[0-9]+:|$)',
                lambda m : '=' + quote(m.group(2)[:int(m.group(1))]) + '&',
                sess.read().rstrip().rstrip(';') + ';')
        )

print(parse_php_session('/session-save-path/sess_0123456789abcdef'))
# {'Id': ['2'], 'Usr': ['AxL11']}
```

It used to work without replacing `;` to `&` (both are allowed). But since Python 3.10 the default separator for `parse_qs` is `&`